# GWT Error when trying to throw an Exception to the Client with RPC

Tags: exception, gwt, null

I am getting some Error when I try to throw an Exception on the Server to the Client with RPC.
What I have is:
An own Exception Class :

```
package catan.user.session.shared;
public class SessionInvalidException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

And the RPC Implementation.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ProfileServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ProfileService{

    @Override
    public UserLight getUser() throws SessionInvalidException {
        SessionManager.getInstance().isSessionStillValid(this.getThreadLocalRequest());
        return ((UserLight)     this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(false).getAttribute("User")).clone();
    }
}
```

The Exception is Thrown in SessionManager.getInstance().isSessionStillValid() 
and when I run my Programm i get the folowing Errors in my log

```
Wed Aug 14 17:13:45 CEST 2013 catan.client.Catan
WARNING: Exception caught 

catan.user.session.shared.SessionInvalidException: null
at catan.user.session.shared.SessionInvalidException_FieldSerializer.instantiate(SessionInvalidException_FieldSerializer.java:16)
at catan.user.session.shared.SessionInvalidException_FieldSerializer.create(SessionInvalidException_FieldSerializer.java:25)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:216)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Aug 14, 2013 5:13:45 PM com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceUtil     logOnServer

WARNING: Exception caught 

com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SerializableThrowable$ThrowableWithClassName
at catan.user.session.shared.SessionInvalidException_FieldSerializer.instantiate(SessionInvalidException_FieldSerializer.java:16)
at catan.user.session.shared.SessionInvalidException_FieldSerializer.create(SessionInvalidException_FieldSerializer.java:25)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:216)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The funny Thing is i have another Exception within the exact same package thrown in the nearly exact same way, with just another name, and it worked... I just don't understand what i am doing wrong...

Comment: When you throw the exception, do you pass some other exception to the constructor as a cause? If the wrapped exception is not in a GWT client package, it could explain the issue.

Comment: does the method signature in your `ProfileService` interface also say `public UserLight getUser() throws SessionInvalidException`? Also, make sure your custom exception class has the default constructor `public SessionInvalidException () {}` because it is needed for serialization.

Comment: @ Churro Yes the ProfileService says so and adding a defaul constructer didn't solve the Problem. Also the Other Exception in the same Package with just another name doesn't need the default construkter to work.

Comment: @ David Levesque I thought about that to. I'm throwing the Exception after catching a NullPointerException. I will try throwing the Exception before the NullPointerException. So this Element will not be in the StackTrace or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved my Problem. So the Exception was correctly passed to the client by the RPC. Then 
in the onFailure method I passed the the caught object to my Logger class which then tried to send it back to the Server or something. I'm not sure here because the Logger class was written by another Member of my Projekt. So just not using this class solved the Problem, but i am still not sure what those Errors try to tell me... If someone is intrested here is the Method i passed the caught Object to. The Catan.class is our EntryPoint class.

```
public class Logger {

/**
 * Logs a Throwable
 * @param caught
 */
public static void log(Throwable caught) {
    final java.util.logging.Logger log = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Catan.class.getName());
    log.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception caught \n", caught);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the exception class is on a path specified by a  element in your *.gwt.xml module definition file. For example:

```
<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />
```

Comment: Yes the Exception is in a shared Package. And it is specified by the *.gwt.xml. Moreover in the same Package is another exception just with another name which works.

Comment: Is there a member field in this exception of a type not in a shared package?